# url rewriting in windows server

Tags: php

I have upload my site on windows server, but when i use .htacess in my site then it is not working. means no page will open it show page not found error. but it is working properly in localhost.I want to know whether windows server support .htaccess(Url rewriting) or not. if it support then how can i enable it on server.

Comment: There is not a thing called "windows server". Do you happen to know **what certain server software you use?** .htaccess works with  Apache only

Answer (score 1):

On windows server you should use `web.config` instead of `.htaccess` for your rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf look for “AccessFileName” and change the value to any valid windows filename (for windows .htaccess is not a valid filename)

Answer (score 0):

Col. Shrapnel: periods at the end and at the beginning of file and folder names is supported by Win32 file I/O Specifications ([As indicated in naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#naming_conventions)); However, Windows Shell prohibits you create files or folders starting or ending with period (Unless you use the 'cmd' shell or created by your own code).

Regardless that, Apache conventions is very flexible. You only needs indicate the name of the file with rules (mod_rewrite activated) and all will be working.